# MySQL - Select rows where a given character is repetable for x times

Tags: mysql

I need to create a select statement in this way:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable where COUNT_CHARACTER('-', mycolumn) = 2
```

It select all rows where the character '-' is present exactly two times in all records.

Is there a function in MySQL as this COUNT_CHARACTER?

Comment: It's the difference between the length of the string, and the length of the string where '-' is replaced with ''.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may play trick

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE (LENGTH(mycolumn) - LENGTH(REPLACE(mycolumn, '-', '')))=2;
```

Comment: Woow thank you so much, but I'm a little bit bewildered that Oracle doesn't provide an exact function for it

Answer (score 1):

This expression usually does the trick.

```
LENGTH(MyField) - LENGTH( REPLACE ( MyField , '-', '') )
```

...

```
SELECT
( 
    SELECT 
        MyField,
        FoundCount = LENGTH(MyField) - LENGTH( REPLACE ( MyField , '-', '') )
    FROM 
        MyTable 
)AS X
WHERE
    FoundCount>2
```